# setnumberformat() in Google Apps Script on multiple conditions (e.g. x<a, x>b) based on guide tokens

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, token, number-formatting

I've always had a hard time understanding properly [number format tokens](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_tokens) and this occasion seems no exception.

A small condition that I place at the bottom of my scripts lets me differentiate how varying ranges of numbers appear on the sheet:

```js
    if (value < 1)               {var a = a.toFixed(8);} 
    if (value > 1 && value < 10) {var a = a.toFixed(4);}
    if (value >=10)              {var a = a.toFixed(2);}
```

I would like to transpose this pattern to the [`setNumberFormat()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) method however for the sake of simplification and hopefully speeding up the scripts.

Now, [this guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#meta_instructions) suggests that specific conditions can be set in order to provide a broader range of possibilities; that's my case I thought, the problem is that I simply can't make the script work:

this one works

```js
  var range = sheet_Numbers.getRange(['C:E']);

  range.setNumberFormat("[<1]###0.########;[>10]####.##;##.####");
```

[image: pic1]
but doesn't produce the expected result: I meant numbers **between 1**  and **10** displaying **4 digits**  after the decimal point, **not 3** .

All my other attempts at applying the guides directions return error instead.
Following the guide I thought I could provide something like this, but that doesn't seem to be the case however:

```js
  var range = sheet_Numbers.getRange(['C:E']);

  range.setNumberFormat("[[<1]####.########;[>10]####.##;####.####];[NEGATIVE FORMAT];[ZERO FORMAT]");
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 5.655 to be rendered as 5.6550(4 digits after the decimal regardless of significance), use `0` instead of `#`

```
"[<1]###0.########;[>10]####.##;##.0000"
```

or more generally

```
"[<1]###0.00000000;[>10]####.00;##.0000"
```

Comment: thanks very much for your answer; I'll look into it tomorrow morning (GMT+2) and try it out. please stand by for further questions :) thanks again

Comment: ok, now suppose you want to complete the formula and provide patterns for ```negative```, ```zero``` and ```text``` format as well, like the guide suggests ```[POSITIVE FORMAT];[NEGATIVE FORMAT];[ZERO FORMAT];[TEXT FORMAT]```: how would you do that, how would you apply it to this pattern we already have?  ```range.setNumberFormat("[<1]###0.########;[>10]####.##;##.####");```

Comment: @John One or the other. You could do meta condition `[]` or default positive / negative format, but not both.